# Problem with simple binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I'm trying to bind a collection to a ListBox using only XAML. It kind of works, but it's only displaying `MyProject.mainItem` (which is the object type), instead of the actual values.

In the class that is assigned as the DataContext, I have this:

```
ItemCatalog.Add(new mainItem { Ref = "555555", ItemName = "First Item" });
```

In the XAML on the page that has the ListBox, I have this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCatalog}">
       <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ref}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="Black" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Foreground="Black" />
             </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It iterates through the entire `ItemCatalog` collection, but instead of displaying values such a `First Item`, it just shows the object's type. thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with silverlight before, but is there a DataSource property or something for "TextBlock" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If main item does not have a visual representation IE a data template. Then it will call the `ToString()` of that object for its display. Which is why you're seeing the object type.

Why your data template is not working, is because you've tried to insert it as you would a `ListBoxItem`.

What you want to do is override the `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCatalog}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate/>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Also you'll want to set your `DataType` property in the `DataTemplate` to the appropriate  type.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I forgot to add the `ItemTemplate` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The code is saying that the DataTemplate is one of the items of the ListBox.

Try adding a `<ListBox.ItemsTemplate>` tag around the `<DataTemplate>`.